# How to determine if next row in datagridview is equal to negative integer?

Tags: vb.net

i got this problem on how to determine if the next row in a datagridview is equal to negative then current row will return a remarks.

For example;

```
Remarks   Reference
  A          1
  A          2
  B          3
            -4
```

If the next row is a positive number, remarks will be A. And if the next row is a negative value, remarks will return B.

I'm struggling in this part.

Here is the code:

```
 For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvSTSub.Rows
        Bal = Bal + r.Cells(3).Value - r.Cells(1).Value
        r.Cells(3).Value = Bal

        If Bal > Bal + r.Cells(3).Value Then
            r.Cells(2).Value = r.Cells(1).Value
        End If
    Next
```

That was not the actual datagridview as shown above but that is what i want to happen.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please show your struggles in this part

Comment: ow sorry i was not able to include my code.

Comment: i have edited my post.. please take a look at it.

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`...

Comment: I would recommend handling the `CellValueChanged` event of the grid and detecting the `Value` of the Reference` column being set.  You would then set the `Value` in the Remarks column of the previous row based on that.  You are provided with a `RowIndex` in the event handler so accessing the previous row is a piece of cake.

Comment: If you did want to stick with a loop then don't use a `For Each` loop.  The obvious solution here is to use a `For` loop.  The loop counter is used as an index into the `Rows` collection so accessing the next or previous row is simple arithmetic.

Comment: That said, a `DataGridViewRow` has an `Index` property so accessing the next or previous row is still a piece of cake event with a `For Each` loop. I'd still consider the `For` loop a better option though, not least because you can set limits and thus easily start at the second row or finish at the second last row.

Comment: Can you share me some code on how to do it? sorry bro, i'm just a beginner in vb.net so i want to learn more with looping with that condition i gave. Please bro. I just badly need it..

Answer (score 0):

From the given data. Remarks is in `cells(0)` and Reference is in `cells(1)`
To determine the negative integers from `cells(1)`:

**Assuming that References contains integers only:** *(use these codes)*

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim number As Integer
    While i <= DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        number = CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
        If number < 0 Then
            MsgBox("Row: " & i & " is Negative number") ' Omit this line if you want.
            ' Add your codes here
        End If
        i += 1
    End While
```